# How to view fast-forward merges in the git log?

Tags: git, smartgit

One of our colleagues did at one point a fast forward (FF) merge and inadvertently FF merged the release branch into the master branch.

I am having a hard time pinpointing exactly when that merge happened (I am using smartgit as well). I looked at git reflog and git log -g but the output doesn't seem to tell me much.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no actual merge to find with a FF, a ref just got moved.

Comment: Is there a way to find when that happened?

Comment: You may be able to find it with reflog on your colleague's machine.

Comment: Why is the release branch **ahead** of the master branch?

Comment: @DanielMann - Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: @DanielMann: master reflects what's in production. release contains the new release currently in test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your colleague's repo, you can do `git reflog master --date=iso`, and you should see at least one entry that looks like this:

```
bd7d6aa master@{2015-12-30 00:33:17 +0000}: merge release/foo: Fast-forward
```